# How to add additional validation to a custom field in MemberPress

Tags: validation, custom-fields, memberpress

I have an original registration form in MemberPress with some custom fields. One of them, is an ID Card. I need to use a custom validation function in my functions.php file to validate this ID Card.

How can I call to this function before submit my form?
If it's not a valid ID card, this field will be show like invalid and don't send the form.

I need this to be used with MemberPress forms.

Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: I was looking for some kind of information me too. It might bring an answer some day.